# How to create custom login page for extended claims-Windows authentication based Internet sharepoint application?

Tags: custom-form, form, windows-authentication

1) I have a Claims Based Windows Authentication web application which is being used by my internal Active Directory users. (Intranet app)

2) Now I want to expose this to the Internet (by configuring a public URL or host name), so that the same AD users can access this web site from outside the company over the Internet. (In any case external users will not have access)

3) To achieve step 2, I extended this web application with Windows Claims Based Authentication and enabled anonymous access. (clearly, I do not want to use FBA as no external users will have access)

4) I achieved my requirement and was able to access the site from the Internet by providing AD user credentials along with the domain name in the prompted Windows security login screen.

5) But I was not able to use a custom login page for the extended web application. It is prompting a windows security login screen as an image (whereas custom login page (aspx page) is working fine if I use FBA. But I don't want to use FBA.)

Can anybody help me? Am I following the right approach? How do I configure a custom login page for Claims Based Windows Authentication?

[image: Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at some of these walk throughs:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/09/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-windows-authentication.aspx

http://jcapka.blogspot.com/2010/12/nicer-claims-login-page-sharepoint-2010.html

http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2011/06/23/sharepoint-2010-custom-login-page/

Unfortunately this isn't a quick answer, but hopefully these resources will help. The code samples should be a good starting point.

Comment: thank you, Will look into it deeper. it is close to my requirement. But it has FBA which I dont want to use.

Comment: The first sample is just Windows Authentication. The second and third have both FBA and Windows Authentication. Pick and choose the code you need. You might use bits from all three, but they'll give you a great example of where to start anyhow.

Comment: but first one doesnt gives authentication codes, it just trying to validate a pin. nothing more.